# handle google authentication code using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, authentication, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I am creating automation script using selenium web driver and java and the most of actions at website require google authentication (2 step verification). at first, developers made the authentication code fixed for all users (in the testing environment)so I can handle my automation scripts then our project manager asked to be the normal code, not the fixed one and I don't know how to handle it, is there any way to generate google authentication code

Comment: What is `google authentication code` all about? Your code trials and the relevant `HTML` please.

Comment: Admin user should generate a key for the user and user should scan QR code on google authinticator app and the google authenticator app generates the OTP code which the user use in login, I didn't try to generate the code yet I only used fixed code that was provided before and I am searching for how to generate the OTP for specific user

Comment: I have found the solution in this article https://dev.to/j_sakamoto/selenium-testing---how-to-sign-in-to-two-factor-authentication-2joi